# How do df['column_name'] and df[['column_name']] work in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I understood the former one gives me a series whereas the letter gives a dataframe. What I couldn't get is its arguments. `df[['column_name']]` is giving dataframe. Is that the reason cuz I'm sending `['column_name']` an iterative as its `data=` parameter? I'm struggling how python is working here! My results are following:

```
df['Yil']=
bir     2021
ikki    2020
19      2019
18      2018
17      2017
16      2016
15      2015
10      2010

df[['Yil']]=

        Yil
bir     2021
ikki    2020
19      2019
18      2018
17      2017
16      2016
15      2015
10      2010
Name: Yil, dtype: int64
```

Comment: `Name: Yil, dtype: int64` seems to be in the wrong place. Seems like you copy-pasted `df[['Yil']]` into the middle

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. I edited your question to remove some unnecessary parts since Stack Overflow is meant to be like a reference ([more details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/4518341)).

Comment: What do you mean by "`data=` parameter"? Are you confusing the dataframe constructor with indexing?

Comment: Related: [Selecting multiple columns in a Pandas dataframe](/q/11285613/4518341), [Keep selected column as DataFrame instead of Series](/q/16782323/4518341)

Answer (score 2):

`df['column_name']` returns a Series that is that column

`df[['column_name']]` returns a DataFrame that has one column named `column_name`

which you clearly noticed...

dataframes have some different methods available to them vs series. it's hard to tell which one you want to use without more info.

Answer (score 1):

For selecting certain columns of a dataframe, the indexing can't be just any iterable. (For example, strings are iterable.) According to [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-label), it has to be a **list**, although from some quick testing, some other iterables will work:

**Iterators**

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 3], 'b': [4, 5], 'c': [6, 7]})

In [3]: df[['a']]
Out[3]: 
   a
0  2
1  3

In [4]: df[iter(['a'])]  # Dummy iterator
Out[4]: 
   a
0  2
1  3

In [5]: df[(x for x in ['a'])]  # Dummy generator, a kind of iterator
Out[5]: 
   a
0  2
1  3
```

**Ranges**

```
In [6]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']])

In [7]: df1[range(1)]
Out[7]: 
   0
0  a
1  c
```

Dicts and sets also work, but they're deprecated.

---

In contrast, a **tuple** *cannot* be used to select multiple columns:

```
In [8]: df[('a',)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
KeyError: ('a',)
```

Because it needs to be possible to do multilevel column indexing:

```
In [9]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(
   ...:    [[2, 4], [3, 5]],
   ...:    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c')]))

In [10]: df2
Out[10]: 
   a   
   b  c
0  2  4
1  3  5

In [11]: df2[('a', 'c')]
Out[11]: 
0    4
1    5
Name: (a, c), dtype: int64
```